# Multiplication of Expected Values

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, self-learning, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the  proof I tried that $E[X*Y] = E[X]*E[Y]$ for independant variables $X,Y$

In this I assign the the multiplicative expected value of X*Y to Z:

$E[Z] = E[X*Y]$

So I can write it like this, (which will try to bring into this form $E[X*Y ] = E[X]*E[Y]$):

$E[Z] = \sum_{\psi \in \Omega} Z(\psi) z* Pr[Z=z]$

Because I deal with independant variables here I can write it like this:

$E[Z] = \sum_{\psi \in \Omega} Z(\psi)* Pr[Y=y \land X = y]$ and then into

$E[Z] = \sum_{\psi \in \Omega} X(\omega)*Y(\phi)*  Pr[Y=y] * Pr[X = y]$

Since $\psi$ (and this is where I am not sure but it needs make sense, can you explain why we do this ?) considers all pairs of $\phi_1\omega_1$ to $\phi_n\omega_n$ we can write the sum of all $\psi$ like

$E[Z] = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega} \sum_{\phi \in \Omega} X(\omega)*Y(\phi)*  Pr[Y=y] * Pr[X = y]$

We can then pull out the constant factors in that nested sum like this and then we can see that the proof is complete

$E[Z] = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega}X(\omega)* Pr[X = x] * \sum_{\phi \in \Omega} Y(\phi)*  Pr[Y=y] $

$E[Z] = (\sum_{\omega \in \Omega}X(\omega)* Pr[X = x])*( \sum_{\phi \in \Omega} Y(\phi)*  Pr[Y=y] )$

$E[Z] = E[X] *  E[Y]$

And the proof is complete at that point, I would like some better insight how $\psi$ was all pairs of $\omega $ and $\phi$

Comment: Why are you starting from $E(XY)$ side? You could say $E(X)E(Y)=\sum_{x} xP(X=x) \sum_{y} yP(Y=y)=\sum_x \sum_y xyP(X=x,Y=y)=\sum_z zP(Z=z)=E(Z)$

Comment: I would stop using the notation $X*Y$ since it usually means "[convolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution)".

Comment: @user160738 i have not considered that, I can see that this direction is easier but can you maybe try to give me some intuition on that $\psi$ term ?

Comment: @Jack what should I use instead ?

Comment: @zython $\psi$ is an element of the sample space $\Omega$, and $Z$ is a random variable which is a (measurable) map from $\Omega$ to, say, $\mathbb{R}$. $Z(\psi)$ is value of $Z$ at $\psi \in \Omega$

Comment: @user160738 I see, I meant to say how $\psi$ correlates to $\phi$ and $\omega$

Comment: I don't quite understand most of your proof, and I think your proof is wrong from the first line where it says $E(Z)=\sum_{\psi} Z(\psi)zP(Z=z)$. This is not the definition of expectation, and you usually do not consider $\Omega$ and $\psi$ explicitly unless you are really dealing with measure theoretic probability theory

Comment: @user160738 okay makes sense, I agree that your way makes more sense .feel free to post the comment as answer I'll accept it

Comment: @zython Thanks, but I don't think my comment is worth being an answer; Probably someone could point out your misunderstandings and explain in more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noting that $\{\{\psi\in\Omega: X(\psi)=x, Y(\psi)=y\}: x\in X(\Omega), y\in Y(\Omega)\}\setminus\emptyset$ is a partition of the sample space, $\Omega$ then:

$$\begin{align}
 \mathsf E(XY) ~&=~\sum_{\psi\in\Omega} X(\psi)Y(\psi)\Pr(\psi) &\because~&{\text{Definition of Expectation} \\ {\tiny\text{(for sample spaces of countable many outcomes)} }}
\\[1ex] &=~ \sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}\sum_{y\in Y(\Omega)}\sum_{\psi:X(\psi)=x, Y(\psi)=y}X(\psi)\,Y(\psi)\,\Pr(\psi) &\because~&\text{Partitioning}
\\[1ex] &=~ \sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}\sum_{y\in Y(\Omega)} x\,y\,\Pr\{\psi: X(\psi)=x,Y(\psi)=y\} &\because~& \text{Sigma Additivity of Probability}
\\[1ex] &=~ \sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}\sum_{y\in Y(\Omega)} x\,y\,\Pr\{\psi:X(\psi)=x\}\Pr\{\psi:Y(\psi)=y\} &\because~&\text{Independence}
\\[1ex] &=~ \sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}\sum_{y\in Y(\Omega)} x\,y\,\Pr\{\psi:X(\psi)=x\}\Pr\{\phi:Y(\phi)=y\} &\because~&\text{Alpha-Substitution}
\\[1ex] &=~ \sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}x \Pr\{\psi:X(\psi)=x\}\cdot\sum_{y\in Y(\Omega)} y\Pr\{\phi:Y(\phi)=y\} 
\\[1ex] &=~ \sum_{\psi\in\Omega} X(\psi)\Pr(\psi)\cdot\sum_{\phi\in\Omega}Y(\phi)\Pr(\phi) &\because~&\text{Partitioning (Reversal)}
\\[1ex] &=~ \mathsf E(X)\cdot\mathsf E(Y) &\because~&\text{Definition of Expectation}
\end{align}$$